# How big was the Star Wars empire?

Tags: star-wars, economics, empire

In the original Star Wars movie, Grand Moff Tarkin destroys a perfectly viable Alderaan seemingly simply to demonstrate imperial ruthlessness.  It then stands to reason that the economic loss was negligible to the Imperium, implying *immense* wealth.
Note there are some that claim that the empire was on the brink of [collapse](http://phys.org/news/2015-12-economics-star-wars-analysis-financialruin.html). Presumably, in that case, Emperor Palpatine simply would not have cared. But this is *not* the sense we get in the first movie. If anything the upper echelons of the empire exuded nothing but confidence!
(Looking at this excellent [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104187/star-wars-the-empire-and-taxation) we get a possible sense of the way the Empire funded itself.)

**Then, can we reasonably estimate the number of worlds in the Empire?**

---

<sub>If we can prove a general statement such as 'it comprised the whole far-far-away galaxy' that would be sufficient proof. Also if it leads to speculation we'll remove it</sub>

Comment: Yep, this would explain why the loss of a few worlds meant nothing to them. _50 million_!!

Comment: I commented on this recently: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109159/do-the-imperials-know-they-are-evil/109192#comment258128_109192 In short: even for lower estimates of Empire size, the (relative) loss was absurdly tiny compared to conflicts that barely get our attention today.