# How rich is the Galactic Republic & Empire?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

How much money does the Galactic Republic have at the eve of the Clone Wars, and the Galactic Empire at its height prior to the destruction of the first Death Star? How wealthy are they if we exclude taking on new bank loans?

Please provide figures if available.

Comment: Very. Very very.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104187/star-wars-the-empire-and-taxation

Comment: @Valorun It was a long, long time ago. So you should adjust for inflation. If $1000 today are like $100 in 1950, probably in the Star Wars time they had like 15$ in total.

Answer (score 4):

According to researchers the size of the economy of the galactic empire at the time of the destruction of the Death Star was $4.6 sextillion. This was worked out based on the cost of the Death Star.

> An assistant professor of electrical and systems engineering at Washington University in St. Louis has estimated the economic toll of Star Wars' fictional Battle of Endor.
>
> Zachary Feinstein, PhD, used the USS Gerald Ford as a model, calculating that the two destroyed Death Stars would cost $193 quintillion and $419 quintillion.
>
> In order to prevent total collapse, a bailout of at least 15 percent of the Galaxy's $4.6 sextillion economy would be required.
>
> To make the calculations, Feinstein applied economic modelling and systemic risk analysis to the Galaxy's economy.

Unfortunately I can't find any modelling that has been done for the specific periods requested.

1. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3343244/The-economics-Galactic-Empire-Researchers-reveal-Star-Wars-baddies-broke-real-life-say-Death-Star-cost-419-quintillion.html
2. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09054v1.pdf
3. 1 sextillion is 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Comment: Flawed argument. Was the USS Gerald Ford built by droids that you don't have to pay and superhumanly strong slave labourers? Were the materials moved around on anti-gravity sleds?

Comment: @Valorum take that up with the university. They're the ones that did the research.

Comment: The person doing the research seems to have a solid grasp on the size of the Death Stars but zero understanding of the in-universe back story relating to their construction.

Comment: @Valorum It is not so simple - robots weren't used only to build the Death Star, they were used for everything in the Universe. Thus, it doesn't distort the model.

Comment: @Morninstar - A large pool of essentially free droid  labour and a large pool of superhuman slave labour don't distort the model? Really?